# Linkage of identifiers in C++ declared with the specifier extern

Tags: c++, c++17, constants, extern, linkage

In the C Standard (6.2.2 Linkages of identifiers) there is written enough clear

> 4 For an identifier declared with the storage-class specifier extern
>   in a scope in which a prior declaration of that identifier is
>   visible,31) if the prior declaration specifies internal or external
>   linkage, the linkage of the identifier at the later declaration is the
>   same as the linkage specified at the prior declaration. If no prior
>   declaration is visible, or if the prior declaration specifies no
>   linkage, then the identifier has external linkage.

However I can not find  a similar statement in the C++ Standard looking through its section 6.5 Program and linkage.

The question arises due to the following quote from the C++ 17 Standard

> 3 A name having namespace scope (6.3.6) has internal linkage if it is
>   the name of
>
> (3.2) — a non-inline variable of non-volatile const-qualified type
>   that is neither explicitly declared extern nor previously declared to
>   have external linkage; or

Now consider the following declarations

```
const int x = 100;
extern const int x;
```

So it is unclear whether the code is ill-formed or the constant `x` has internal linkage though it is declared with the specifier `extern` or the Standard has a defect in the description of this paragraph or I missed the quote in the C++ Standard similar to the quote from the C Standard.

Comment: If you look at section 10.1.1 Storage Class Specifiers, paragraph 6, there are a few examples.  There isn't one that matches your case, but there is a `static int b; // b has internal linkage` `extern int b; // b still has internal linkage` one that comes close.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Examples are not the description.:) Apart from example there must be a description saying that these examples are valid.

Comment: Wow. I wasn't aware of this subtlety (i.e. that the order I always used "intuitively" is that important). I made a [**sample on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f1199287df5ed42b) to illustrate this.

Comment: Well, [\[dcl.stc\]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.stc#6.sentence-2) does contain normative sentence saying that the linkages must agree.

Comment: @cpplearner Again the quote does not say about using the specifier extern in a latter declaration. It assumes that this was already described.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a defective in [basic.link#6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.link#6), After looking at the [dcl.stc#5](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.stc#5), it says:

> For the linkage of a name declared with an extern specifier, see [basic.link].

However, the rule about declaration declared with a `extern` specifier is mostly in [basic.link#6], which is:

> The name of a function declared in block scope and the name of a variable declared by a block scope extern declaration have linkage. If such a declaration is attached to a named module, the program is ill-formed. If there is a visible declaration of an entity with linkage, ignoring entities declared outside the innermost enclosing namespace scope, such that the block scope declaration would be a (possibly ill-formed) redeclaration if the two declarations appeared in the same declarative region, the block scope declaration declares that same entity and receives the linkage of the previous declaration. If there is more than one such matching entity, the program is ill-formed. Otherwise, if no matching entity is found, the block scope entity receives external linkage. If, within a translation unit, the same entity is declared with both internal and external linkage, the program is ill-formed.

It sounds like that these rules only applies to block scope declaration instead of applying to namespace scope declaration that declared with extern specifier. Except for this paragraph, there is no more rule in section [basic.link] that indicates what the linkage of a name declared by `extern` specifier.  Unlike what says in C standard, the rules apply to whatever declarations declared with `extern` specifier(regardless of what kind of scopes where the declarations declared).

Comment: It’s actually /3 and /4 that are relevant, even though they barely mention `extern`.  A lot of handwaving occurs around words like “above”, though.

Comment: @DavisHerring  In my humble opinion, that's not apparently.  I think something shall be added to [dcl.stc] to specially state what abilities `extern` specifier are(e.g, how could the variable specified by `extern` link a variable that have linkage)

Comment: Balancing non-redundancy and accessibility is hard, and we sometimes have to fall back on “the standard is not a tutorial”.  [basic.link] certainly could use clarification, but realize that `extern` **never** really affects linkage; it *applies* it to what would otherwise be local variables, but otherwise it mostly just prevents declarations from being definitions (which is why it never means anything for functions).  External linkage is simply the default (before C++20 makes it sometimes be module linkage).

Comment: @DavisHerring However, the current standard is weak to state which entity will be linked to a variable that specified by `extern`.  The `basic.link#6` only says about block scope variable but not such as a variable that has namespace scope(specified by `extern`). Even though `P1787`, it just removed the whole  basic.link#6 and didn't give new wording instead.

Comment: P1787’s [basic.link]/9 makes it very clear which sets of declarations declare the same entity.  It’s just that, outside of a function, `extern` does not affect that determination at all except by disabling the (historical) implicit `static` on const variables.

Comment: @DavisHerring I don't know whether I have understood P1787 correctly. First, it introduces a new concept, that is "declaration correspond". About this concept, The definition seems to say that, as long as these names are the same and do not satisfy the bullet follows "unless..."(namely, regardless of whether these declaration are in the same scope), then they will be considered to declaration correspond, Right?

Comment: Then the rule about the same entity is that shall satisfy some conditions, such as they correspond, and have the same target scope and shall satisfy any of the 
following bullet, then they will be? As you said in the other comment, that is `extern` affects the target scope ([dcl.meaning]). I only see a note in P1787 that says the target of `extern` block scope variable is the enclosing namespace scope, but otherwise, there's no formal rule in that page.

Comment: Sorry, there's a formal rule in P1787, that is "If the declaration inhabits a block scope S and declares a function ([dcl.fct]) or uses the extern specifier, the declaration shall not be attached to a named module ([module.unit]) and its target scope is the innermost enclosing namespace scope, but the name is bound in S. "

Comment: Yes, correspondence ignores scope, so that it can be used for checking other things like *using-declaration*s and redeclarations (including friends).

Comment: @DavisHerring  Thanks. In addition, I think the comments in this example ````struct X {
  static void f();
  void f() const;  // error: redeclaration
  void g();
  void g() const;  // OK
  void g() &;      // error: redeclaration
};
```` which is in P1787 may make misleading, per the rule of corresponding declaration, even though they are the corresponding declarations(both declare functions with the same parameter-type-list). however, AFAIK, the actually reason for why they're ill-formed is that they violate [Overloadable declarations]. Do you think so?

Comment: The comments are correct, although they could also say that they give the same entity different types: P1787 *also* removes [over.load], stating instead that such “invalid” distinctions are ignored when considering whether declarations declare the same entity.

Comment: @DavisHerring  Do you mean that the corresponding rule is  replaced by:  For any two declarations of an entity: If one declares it to be a variable or function, the other shall declare it as one of the same type. Right?

Comment: Yes, that’s the generalization/replacement.

Comment: @DavisHerring  Alright, forgive my trouble. How about the example `int f(int x,int x);  // error: different entities for x`?  IMHO, their declaration correspond, and they have the same target scope and in the same TU. they should have denoted the same entity. however the comment doesn't say that. In my pass experience, the actually reason should be that it violates `ODR`.

Comment: Those aren’t definitions, and +[basic.link]/9 excludes function parameter scopes.  (If you have so many questions about P1787, perhaps just ask a new question?  It’s been approved, although the editors are still applying it.)

Comment: @DavisHerring These doubts are from my reading for P1787, It's not sufficient to let me post a question. So, I asked these questions to you here.  The wording is "have the same target scope that is not a function or template parameter scope". For this sentence, I didn't know whether it means "have the same target scope that is not a function or (template parameter) scope" or "have the same target scope that is not a (function) or (template) parameter scope". I understand it as the first meaning, namely function scope or template parameter scope. It seems to different with you.

Comment: There are no function scopes (anymore).

Comment: @DavisHerring Do you mean P1787 removed [basic.funscope](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.funscope)?  And, since that declaration is not a function definition, so the parameter is a declaration not definition (it is a parameter-declaration in a function declarator that is not the declarator of a function-definition, [basic.def#2.8]), and they have function parameter scope which is excluded by the rule for the same entity, hence, they are not the same entity and violate...

Comment: "Two declarations potentially conflict if they correspond and cause their shared name to denote different entities ([basic.link]). The program is ill-formed if, in any scope, a name is bound to two declarations that potentially conflict and one precedes the other"